# react-console-emulator welcome message renders twice

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Okay! so i am making terminal like portfolio site using `react-console-emulator`
but while making this in development mode i always get the welcome message twice

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM38D.png)

but it should be rendered once according to documentation. This error only occur in development mode .After build in nextjs it only rendered once.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import Terminal from 'react-console-emulator'

const commands = {
  echo: {
    description: 'Echo a passed string.',
    usage: 'echo <string>',
    fn: function () {
      return `${Array.from(arguments).join(' ')}`
    }
  }
}

export default class MyTerminal extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Terminal
        commands={commands}
        style={{
            backgroundColor: null,
            minHeight: "100vh",
            height: '100%',
            maxHeight: "100vh",
            overflow: 'auto',
            width: '100%',
            padding: "10px 0px",
            fontFamily: "Hack"
        }}
        welcomeMessage={'Welcome to the React terminal!'}
        promptLabel={'me@React:~$'}
        contentStyle={{ color: 'var(--th-primary)', fontWeight: 'normal', paddingLeft: null, fontFamily: "Hack" }}
        promptLabelStyle={{ color: 'var(--th-primary)', fontWeight: 'normal', paddingTop: null, fontFamily: "Hack" }}
        inputTextStyle={{ color: 'var(--th-secondary)', fontWeight: 'normal', paddingTop: null, fontFamily: "Hack" }}
        messageStyle={{ color: 'var(--th-secondary)', fontWeight: 'normal', paddingLeft: null, fontFamily: "Hack" }}
       
      />
    )
  }
}
```

I tried to make welcome message rendered once but couldn't.

Comment: maybe tryy to go to your index.js and see if <React.StrictMode> exist then remove it

Comment: @AousMohammad This worked for me but I don't know the reason, can you explain ?